# Stack Overflow Welcome Wagon

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

When you move to a new town (at least where I'm from), there's something called the Welcome Wagon. They connect with you, touch base, spam you with ads for local businesses, and they offer minimal help in getting you feeling comfortable/connected in your new town.

Over the years that I've been on Stack Overflow, I've seen the site evolve in ways that attempt to correct the eternal problem of newcomers using the site very badly. At one point, I remember a proposal to make a "how to post a question on Stack Overflow" SE site. I believe it was eventually withdrawn when we realized that the mathematics to solve the number of recursively required "how to how to how" SE sites just didn't exist.

Anyway, this problem continues and every day [I see new people post really terrible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736699/secure-input-during-runtime-afterwards/29737317?noredirect=1) and you know, it's not entirely their fault. But even if it is their fault, what do we do about it? I think the current solution is vote close and try to explain why. This pretty much just shuts the user down, and they're left crying alone in the rain feeling booted out of the club.

My suggestion is a sort of welcome wagon. What if we had the system assign a trusted (higher rep) user to one or two (at most at a time) new users and, when they post a question, the welcomer gets a flag the same way we get message notices now (for at least the first couple of posts, not forever). The welcomer can then view and review the content of the newcomer before they get hammered to death with "WHY DIDN"T YOU READ THE FAQ?!? BLARRRRRRRGHHH" comments combined with close votes and flags, and actually mentor/help them into integrating into the community successfully.

Also I personally think the name welcome wagon is silly; I'm not suggesting we create something and call it that. I'm just drawing from the example of it to provoke discussion about an issue that we've tried to solve but persists.

Comment: I feel like higher rep users would not be all that keen to jump on the welcome wagon. It doesn't sound like much fun.

Comment: "What if we had the system assign a trusted (higher rep) user to one or two (at most at a time) new users and" - That only works when you have a high enough ratio of avid users to new users. The problem is that new users posting bad questions outnumber avid users at least 100 to 1. IOW, each of us would need to babysit hundreds if not thousands of new users every day. Personally, I have neither the time nor the patience to do that.

Comment: @Mysticial I guess I didn't realize that there's that many brand new users daily. I think retroactively applying this would be bad for sure, but if we implemented it going forward only, are there really that many new registrations daily?

Comment: @DonkeyKong You're right it isn't fun at all. But the problem is we end up doing it anyway, just in a less constructive way. We get our review log filled up, we find posts on our fave' tags and have to close or edit them or comment to the user. And if we neglect to do this, it gets backlogged onto the mods. We do the job either way. I'm just trying to provoke thought on a possibly better way.

Comment: I wholeheartedly appreciate attempting to provoke thought on the subject. I agree with @Mysticial though, I'm not quite sure this is feasible. And in 2014 it was ~ 3500 new users a day.

Comment: @DonkeyKong lol wow. That's a lot.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141343/a-swat-team-of-nice

Comment: *wow, -16 votes* that's harsh. I don't think it's *that* bad of an idea. FWIW when I comment on a user's question who has 1 Rep I always try to begin by saying **"Welcome to StackOverflow!"** and I go out of my way to be more polite and verbose in explanation if I'm going to tell them there's a problem with their question.

Comment: I like this idea and agree that it is not feasable as currently stated, but what if we added other conditions, to make it more feasable and to only give this to new users who 1) are worth keeping (not beyond help) and 2) users who actually want help? Also high rep users must have an option to opt out.

Comment: > "it's not entirely their fault" — oh, really?

Comment: ***2018 UPDATE*** Now days the SO/SE team have groups of employees, machine learning initiatives, and blog posts dedicated this that are actually use this term (*Welcome Wagon*) frequently. Whoever the OP is of this heavily downvoted question and deleted account deserves an apologize and like 10000 rep points. It's like they tried to convince use their idea to invent the mouse or GUI OS was good, but the community laughed and turned up its nose like Xerox did.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

New users have access to many expert "welcomers" via the review queues, in particular the [triage queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage). [Here is a great example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7751048) of a new user hitting that queue with a badly asked and formatted question. This queue gives reviewers the opportunity to edit posts when needed and the best thing about it is **you can be a part of it**.

> you know, it's not entirely their fault.

You're right in the same sense that it's not a baby's fault that they crap their diaper. In every other sense it *is* their fault. I continue to be surprised at the level of incompetence and laziness shown by new users - these people are studying programming or trying to program but they will never succeed in this field unless they learn how to structure information, ask decent questions and think logically.

It might sound harsh, but fundamentally our primary aim is not to parent new users or to teach them the basics of how to ask a good question*; our aim is to build a world class archive of programming related knowledge. The sheer volume of garbage input coming in means that it is impractical to screen or filter it in any way that isn't largely automated.

There is a part in all (most) of us that wants everyone to be included and to have a great initial experience. However you also need to recognize that many of the new users are similar to crack junkies - they just want a hit and they want it *now*. The "hit" is a working answer to their question, and the overwhelming urge is the pressure of who they are supplying the work to. Idealistic goals of breaking that bad question cycle are all well and good, but from a business perspective the return on investment is negative - even if you had the resources to allocate to the problem.

<sup>* despite me saying that, Stack Exchange has poured a lot of time and energy into help resources so that if a user bothers to look they can find everything they need. And if they're still not sure they can hit Meta for clarification.</sup>

Comment: lol @ baby diapers. Believe me I know, it blows me away too some of them. I actively participate in editing/reviewing (just not so much through the actual review tool) but what always happens is just a rapid hammering of vote to close followed by usually venting/frustrated comments about how crap the post is. You can see in the question/answer I linked that the answer provided is by a not new but low rep user who knows the post is crap but is trying to reach out and educate before the new user is pushed away.

Comment: I think my point is that we can see from even the lower rep users who actually made it past rep 1 have this perception that integrating into the community is a very difficult process that is harsh when you make a mistake.

Comment: Marked your answer as correct, burn the welcome wagon. I guess we'll just keep on keepin on.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Thanks :)  You have good intentions, it's just unfortunate they're not practical.

Comment: yeah I didn't realize the sheer volume of new users. Oh well, #yolo

Comment: **our aim is to build a world class archive of programming related knowledge.** .. where did you get this notion from? time and time again it has been state the intention is foster a community, and to destinquish members of that community..

Comment: @BrettCaswell I got that from being around the site for 6.5 years, it has been mentioned many times in that period.